# Foreign Key of Foreign Key not available in admin change form

Tags: django, django-admin

My schema:

```
class Component():
  comp_id = models.CharField('Component ID', primary_key=True, db_column='comp_id')
  path = models.CharField('Path')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.path

class Configuration():
  config_id = Models.AutoField('Config ID', db_column='config_id', primary_key=True)
  component = models.ForeignKey('Component', db_column='component')
  org_id = models.Integer.Field('Org ID')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "{} + {}".format(self.org_id, self.component)

class Result():
  result_id = Models.AutoField('Result ID', db_column='result_id', primary_key=True)
  config = models.ForeignKey('Configuration', db_column='config')
```

In the change form for Result, I expected the config foreign key to be represented by a dropdown.  But instead the page won't render and I get DatabaseError exception with message: "Attempt to initiate a new SQL Server operation with results pending."  What I think is happening, is that the Result.config dropdown is trying to resolve the unicode representations for the Configurations, but that means going one foreign key level deeper to resolve the unicode for the related Component and the database won't allow it.  Anyone see a way around this error?

Comment: I don't think that's the cause of your database error. This is a perfectly normal thing to do, and shouldn't cause problems. Have you tried to confirm your suspicion by changing the `__unicode__` method so it doesn't reference the ForeignKey?

Comment: Yep, if I remove self.component from Configuration.__unicode__ then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my installation relies on a custom DB backend for MS SQL Server and I needed to edit it's base.py file to include the following line in the DatabaseFeatures class:

```
can_use_chunked_reads = False
```